# How to sort json data in groovy in alphabetic order?

Tags: json, sorting, groovy

I want to sort an json data which is like this

```
def json = []
for ( int i=10;i>1;i--){

    if (i==10 || i==9 ){
         json << [ name:"xyz",
            id:i
        ]
    }else 
    if (i==8 || i==7 ){
          json << [ name:"abc",
             id:i
            ]
    }

}
// def jsondata = [success:true, rows:json]

def jsondata = [success:true, rows:json.sort(false) { it.name }]

print jsondata​
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.sort() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Boolean, com.cs.AdminController$_closure15_closure83) values: [false, com.cs.controllers.AdminController$_closure15_closure83@3e020351]
Possible solutions: sort(), sort(java.util.Comparator), sort(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), size(), size()
```

I want that data to be sorted alphabetic order ascending or descending

above one is working in a groovy console but not in my program , do i need to add something else like lib ?

Comment: Can you actually give a working example of how you're building your list? Currently your `I am generting the json like this` seems to have no relation to your output json

Comment: apologies for that , actually that is a part of code . The actual code works like it runs in a for loop and combines some part of the result with a random variable and creates a json data of random names .

Comment: What version of Groovy is this?  `sort(boolean, Closure)` has existed for years and years and years...

Comment: That was released 11 May 2010!!!!?

Comment: yup i am not sure about exact date but it was at that time

Comment: any shortcuts like this one for sorting ascending or descending ?

Comment: tried anything? not even tried: `json.sort { it.name }.reverse()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output format seems to have no similarity to your code you posted

Also, your code you posted cannot just be run by someone trying to answer this question.

So this will be an educated guess...

Try:

```
def jsondata = [success:true, rows:json.sort(false) { it.name }, total:totalCount]
```

If you're using groovy from way back in the day for some unknown reason, then just drop the `false`, but beware as this will mutate your `json` list...

```
def jsondata = [success:true, rows:json.sort { it.name }, total:totalCount]
```

Comment: one more thing how can i revese the order like alphaphed desc or asc